# How to input table html to PHP email code

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

This is my current code:

[image: current code]

and I want to add a number of tables to change the design of the email, I am very new to PHP and ZEND any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Prepend each line of your code with four spaces so we can actually read it.

Comment: The other way around, actually.

Comment: What does 'table' mean in this ?

Comment: So a html table which classic emails are made up of.

Comment: Classical emails don't contain html. Emails are plain text. Introducing html in emails makes them extremely risky for the receiver. You should not do that.

Comment: You use `<table>` tags like you would in normal HTML. See [this page](http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails) for a quick how-to-make-everything-look-pretty. But yeah, HTML support for emails is just... terrible.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike Brant said, you can create your HTML then copy in inline.  However you will then need to ensure that the email is sent with the proper mime-type so that the user's email reader knows to render as HTML and not as plain text.  It isn't that hard, but I found that the PEAR mail and mail_mime libraries really make it even easier and more obvious what's being done.  There are also some 3rd party email apis, for example I've had good success on one project using http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start is to just layout your email in HTML the way you want it and then just copy into your HEREDOC section and replace the content with the variables.

Comment: Ok so I've got my html ready to go, shall I just echo ' <table code>';? withint the middle of the PHP?

Comment: I would put you table tag structure in the HTML document itself.  Or if you are building the table dynamically in PHP, then you can inserts it into the HEREDOC using {$table_html} or similar

Answer (score 0):

- Create one (zend)layout for your e-mails like you do it for your website. Best with html 4.0 doctype. Avoid CSS. Most E-Mail Clients cannot render it correctly. If you have to use CSS, embed it into style-tags (no external content) and embed the style-Tag into the body. (most web-mailers are dropping the head-section).
- Now create views for every mail-type you want to send (e.g.: registration, pw-lost,...)
- assign the variables to the view and render it into the layout. Render the Layout into Zend-Email Object.

If you want to manage the content, subject, sender,... over an administration-area, just create a table with the following colums:

1. type (can be registration, pw-Lost...)
2. Subject
3. From
4. To (for mails which are adressed to the admin e.g.: when users post comments)
5. CC
6. Bcc
7. Html-Text (the Text of the e-Mail with Place-Holders for personalzation)
8. Text (optional plain text containing Place-Holders) you can pack this text additionaly to you html-Mail or just send html or Text Depending on the user settings.
9. Some extra-colums for attachments (optional)

Now you can adminster the different Mails and drop your views (not the layout).

At least create a mail-class which you can access in that way:

```
$mail = new My_Mail(My_Mail::PW_LOST);

$mail->bind($userData); // will replace the placeholders in the text

$mail->addTo(...);

$mail->send(); // will replace the placeholders in the text, renders the layout, Sends the mail.
```

**Code-Sample:**
I can provide code samples on saturday if you are interested

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Zend_Mail class (Zend/Mail.php) to send emails. The details are in the code sample below:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText($bodyText);
$mail->setBodyHtml($bodyHtml);
$mail->setFrom($senderAddress, $senderLabel);
$mail->addTo($recipientAddress, $recipientLabel);
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->send();
```

A question you might have is how the email (text and html) contents are assigned to $bodyText and $bodyHtml. You can create a couple of phtml files one for html content and the other for text. See the code below on how to achieve this:

```
$this->view->fullname = "John Abc";
$this->view->emaildata = $data //Possibly an array of data from the db
$bodyText = $this->view->render('emails/htmlemail.phtml')
$bodyHtml = $this->view->render('emails/textemail.phtml')
```

Note: This snippet should be above the previous one.

Hope this answers your questions. Happy coding :)